# How can I add new POS tag in spacy for English

Tags: nlp, spacy

For POS tagging, I am using spacy. I found pos tags for gerund and infinitives are not given. How can I add these two new tags in spacy? I can change tags within the list but not able to add new tags. Please help. Thank you.

```
**pattern = [tokens[t].pos_== "VERB" and tokens[t-1].pos_=="ADP" for t in range 
(len(tokens)-1)]
 spacy.pipeline.tagger.Tagger.add_label(u"GERUND")**
```

this gives error:

```
 TypeError: add_label() takes exactly 2 positional arguments (1 given)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than modifying the output, it sounds like you should just use the `.tag_` attribute, which is more detailed and language specific. In this case the value will be VB for an infinitive and VBG for a gerund. These are [Penn Treebank Tags](https://www.ling.upenn.edu/courses/Fall_2003/ling001/penn_treebank_pos.html).

The `.pos_` values are from Universal Dependencies, and are less detailed but appropriate for multi-lingual applications.

Comment: But if you need a custom POS, what would you suggest ? How to go about it ?

Comment: To add a new POS tag, you need to add a bunch of training data with tagged examples. You would probably also want to modify the attribute ruler for your language to make sure `.pos_` is set correctly.